# How to add a fileassociation to a Wix Project with Harvest Project and VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix

I can't seem to find any answer with Google so its time to ask this...

I Have a application with a custom application, Silver Monkey, a Bot for the mmoRPG Furcadia. I've just started using Wix a few months ago so I'm still learning the roape.. My Project compile fine but when I add a file assocation code to my Product.wxs file I get N eerror.

the Code is 
Ok I’ve updated the snippet

`</Component>
      <Component Id="SilverMonkeyExt" Guid="{DEC333A0-7393-4097-AB77-A2847D121A3C}">
        <File Id="SilverMonkey" Source="$(var.SilverMonkey2.TargetDir)SilverMonkey.exe" KeyPath="no" Checksum="yes" />
    <ProgId Id='SilverMonkeys' Description='Bot information File' >
      <Extension Id='bini' ContentType='application/BotInformationFile'>
        <Verb Id='open' Command='Open' TargetFile='SilverMonkey' Argument='"%1"' />
      </Extension>
    </ProgId>
  </Component>`

Now I get the Error
Failed to compare two elements in the array.      Setup    light.exe
Could there be a conflict with the Harvest project? I’mm using w 4.0 just released in july

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Problem-with-file-association-and-harvesting-files-td7016927.html)

I found out I could use SetProperty
Like

```
 <SetProperty Id='FileAssociationProperty'
Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]\SilverMonkey.exe" After="CostFinalize"/>
```

and then I can use it with Target Property in the verb

```
<ProgId Id="SilverMonkey.exe"  Description="Silver Monkey File type" Advertise="no" >
  <Extension Id="bini"  ContentType="Text/Plain" Advertise="no" >
    <Verb Command="Open" Id="open" TargetProperty="FileAssociationProperty"
    Argument="%1" />
  </Extension>
</ProgId>
```

Its Possible to transform the output with an XSLT file but that over head is too much for me to learn right now